# Fetch/cherry-pick Commit [Without REF] from different repo

Tags: git

I got 2 similar repos **A** & **B**
The commit which i try to access is : **SHA-1**

This is really easy, if the commit which I'm trying to access would have some REF specified, but it doesn't, looks like the REF was somehow lost. I got only the SHA-1 of the commit.

The way I would do it right now would be :

On repo **A**

```
git remote add repo_b path/to/repo_b.git
git fetch repo_b
git cherry-pick SHA-1
```

Is there anyway for me to avoid fetching whole repository refs and only do a fetch/cherry-pick directly on that commit ?

## edit

I got the access to the parent as well

Answer (score 0):

To do a cherry-pick operation, you need both the commit itself and its parent (along with their `tree` and `blob` objects), so that you can convert the commit to a patch.  You can then attempt to apply the patch.

To *get* the commit and its parent with normal Git transport operations, however, you need a reference by which the commit is reachable.  (Just as you remarked: `git fetch` it, perhaps with a specific reference name and/or `--depth` to limit the number of objects you bring into your own repository.)

If that's not available, you need some alternative method (other than normal Git transports).  That might include some kind of web interface, in which case you will need to know what URLs invoke what methods on the server.  Or, you can try using [`git archive`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-archive.html).

While `git archive` is normally something you would run on your local repository to bundle up your own commit, it has a `--remote` option, which invokes [`git upload-archive`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-upload-archive.html) on the server.  See that documentation for notes about security, including whether "naked" hash IDs are allowed.  Note that you will still need both the commit *and its parent*.

If you have direct access to the server, the easiest method (by far) is to convert the commit to a patch using [`git format-patch`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-format-patch.html).  Take the resulting patch back and use `git am` to apply it and make a commit from the result, just as `git cherry-pick` would.

Comment: Well, I have the access to the parent, any more hints if I got this ?

Comment: Once you have both the commit and the parent, diff the two trees (`git diff` if you have them as actual commit objects, some other diff—you *can* get Git to do this, it's just more tricky—if you have them as archives or whatever). Then use `git apply` to apply the patch, and `git commit` with the message from the to-be-picked commit.